# Find a file with today's date as the filename

Tags: unexpectendoffile

I want to find a file with today's date as the filename in Linux.

```
CONFIG="/usr/local/KDS/etc/psp.conf

#result=`find -name $CONFIG.`date +%Y%m%d``
result=`find -path $CONFIG -name ".psp.conf.`date +%Y%m%d`"`

#$(date +%Y%m%d)

if [[$result -eq 0]];
then
#echo "no need to create";
cp -p /usr/local/KDS/etc/psp.conf{,.`date +%Y%m%d`}
else
#cp -p /usr/local/KDS/etc/psp.conf{,.`date +%Y%m%d`}
echo "no need to create";
fi
```

It does not work.

Comment: I would avoid nesting the commands like that and instead save `date +%Y%m%d` to a variable. Also the result variable will return the list of files which have been found. If you want the return code you should use `$?`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

```
> touch .psp.conf.`date +%Y%m%d`
```

To search:

```
> DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
> result=`find . -name ".psp.conf.$DATE"`
```

After that I have

```
> echo "$?"
0
> echo "$result"
./.psp.conf.20150701
```

Answer (score 0):

result=`find -path $CONFIG -name "psp.conf.$DATE"`

echo $result

if [[ $result -eq 0 ]];
then
        cp -p /usr/local/KDS/etc/psp.conf{,.$DATE}
else
        echo "psp.conf.$DATE already exists."
fi

Why this does not work? It didnt echo already exists even though there is file there?